# undefined method `update_attribute' for ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I was trying to update a record in the database using `Object.update_attributes(:field => "parameter")`
To show a simple example of what I was trying to do is this. Please see the code below

```
a = params["ORDERNO"].to_s
b =  params["TRACKNO"].to_s    
@bd=Staging.where(:trackno => b , :orderno=> a)
    if @bd.nil? 
       puts "not found"
    else
       @bd.update_attributes(:field_name => "PARAMETER")
    end
```

I also tried `@bd.first.update_attributes(::field_name => "PARAMETER")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A possible solution for this

use `update_all(:field_name => "PARAMETER")`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Given `User.where(login: 'admin').update_all locked_at: nil`, AR generates `UPDATE users SET users.locked_at = NULL WHERE users.login = 'admin'`. That lets the DB take care of business without instantiating excessive Ruby objects.

Comment: Worth noting that this does run callbacks like update_attributes does.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that there is only one staging correpsponding to (trackno, orderno) 
You can try something like this

```
@bd =Staging.find_by_trackno_and_orderno(b,a)
if @bd
  @bd.update_attributes(:field_name => value)
else
  #whatever you want to do
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query `@bd=Staging.where(:trackno => b , :orderno=> a)` returns an array of objects.

`Array` usually doesn't have `#update_attributes` method. So you need to rewrite your query to fetch only 1 object or iterate through all the objects in the query result using each: `@bd.each{|r| r.update_attributes(:field_name => "PARAMETER")}`

But iterating isn't the right way to update many records, because it calls update query for each object you want to update.

Comment: This is incorrect, because `where()` returns an object based on `ActiveRecord::Relation`, for further builder methods. Such as `update_all`...